# Problem iterating an array into a form Element in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have the following data below.anytime i map through it into the form element and i try to click the radio button for the next question the first question which is checked becomes uncheck and vice-versa if i go back to the first question. and i would love to get the values of the two questions answered.

```
class Exam extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            question : [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "question": "what is the name of a boy",
                    "A": "tope",
                    "B": "tosin",
                    "C": "tayo",
                    "D": "tolu",
                    "Answer" : "A",
                    "chosen": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "question": "what is the name of a girl",
                    "A": "Kanyin",
                    "B": "Kanmi",
                    "C": "Keji",
                    "D": "Kaffy",
                    "Answer" : "A",
                    "chosen": ""
                }
            ]
        }
        this.markPaper = this.markPaper.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    }

    markPaper = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.chosen)  
    alert(this.state.chosen)
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(event.target.value)                 
        this.setState({
            chosen: event.target.value
        }) 

    }


    render() {



        return (
            <form>
                {
                    this.state.question.map((set) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={set.id}>
                                <p>{set.question}</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="A" onChange={this.handleChange}   />{set.A}
                                <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="B" onChange={this.handleChange}  />{set.B}
                                <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="C" onChange={this.handleChange}  />{set.C}
                                <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="D" onChange={this.handleChange}  />{set.D} 
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear ? You want the values to be kept even when you navigate through pages ?

Comment: what i want is when i do a console.log i shoulf get the values for the two input checked

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the option is selected or not for each question.

```
 <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="A" onChange={this.handleChange}  
     checked={set.chosen === set.A} />{set.A}
 <input type="radio" name="chosen" value="B" onChange={this.handleChange} 
     checked={set.chosen === set.B} />{set.B}
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="C" onChange={this.handleChange} 
     checked={set.chosen === set.C} />{set.C}
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="D" onChange={this.handleChange} 
     checked={set.chosen === set.D} />{set.D}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the name...
instead of

```
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="A" onChange={this.handleChange}   />
```

use :

```
<input type="radio" name={set.id} value="A" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

the issue is because all radio button have same name, hence they behave together as single radio input, rather than being separate set, each radio input has name chosen....

setting name of input to `set.id` allows you to have separate input...

> I have found another issue in your code, after you select the radio button the state does not update... you should check on that...

Comment: working but how do i get the value of the two inputs checked it only returns one

Answer (score 0):

The `radio inputs` are grouped by your attribute `name`, e.g.:

```html
<p>Select ur favorite language:</p>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="js" name="fav-language" value="js"
         checked>
  <label for="js">JavaScript</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="php" name="fav-language" value="php">
  <label for="php">PHP</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="python" name="fav-language" value="python">
  <label for="python">Python</label>
</div>

<p>Select ur favorite space tab:</p>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="tab-0" name="fav-space" value="0"
         checked>
  <label for="tab-0">0 spaces</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="php" name="fav-space" value="php">
  <label for="tab-2">2 spaces</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="python" name="fav-space" value="python">
  <label for="tab-4">4 spaces</label>
</div>
```

If you run above code, you will to note that the check boxes in questions "Select ur favorite language" and "Select ur favorite space tab" do not interfere with each other.

I change your code to good operation, check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-grass-m7d54?file=/src/App.js).

Also check [the real documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) to more details.

Comment: you forget that i am loopin through an array a into form element

Comment: I don't forget this bro, i don't remove the method `map` from your array, [check here](https://imgur.com/sR1u8C5)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after...

> I am changing the way you are handling your state and other little things...

see the problem is that your state is `{ chosen : answer }` , as you can see the state stores only one answer, and it does not know which set it is.

Your state should be like:

`{chosen:{ question1: answer1,question2: answer2...} }`

now let's implement this..

the handleChange event should be:

```
handleChange = setId => {
  return (event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value);                 
    this.setState({
      chosen: {...this.state.chosen,[setId]:event.target.value}
    }); 
  }     
}
```

now we have covered the major part..

update your input element :

```
<input type="radio" name="chosen" value="A" onChange={this.handleChange}   />
```

with this:

```
<input type="radio" name={set.id} value="A" checked={this.state.chosen[set.id] == "A"} onChange={this.handleChange(set.id)}/>
```

> Complete Code Comming...

## OR You Can Follow This Method

It will work very well but many minor changes...

```
function RadioInput(props){
  return(
      <>
      <input type="radio" name={props.set.id} value={props.value} check={props.value == props.set.chosen} onChange={props.handleChange}/> {props.set.choices[props.value]}
      </>
  )

}
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            questions : [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "question": "what is the name of a boy",
                    "choices":{
                        "A": "tope",
                        "B": "tosin",
                        "C": "tayo",
                        "D": "tolu",
                    },
                    "answer" : "A",
                    "chosen": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "question": "what is the name of a girl",
                    "choices":{
                        "A": "kaneyi",
                        "B": "maneyi",
                        "C": "tayosa",
                        "D": "toluli",
                    },
                    "answer" : "A",
                    "chosen": ""
                },

            ]
        }
    }


    handleChange = setId => {

      return (event)=>{

        console.log(event.target.value);                 
        this.setState({
          questions: this.state.questions.map((question)=>{
            if(question.id == setId){
              question.chosen = event.target.value
              return question
            }else{
              return question
            }
          })
        }); 
      }     
   }


    render() {



        return (
            <form>
                {
                    this.state.questions.map((set) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={set.id}>
                                <p>{set.question} ?</p>
                                <RadioInput handleChange={this.handleChange(set.id).bind(this)} set={set} value={"A"}  />
                                <RadioInput handleChange={this.handleChange(set.id).bind(this)} set={set} value={"B"}  />
                                <RadioInput handleChange={this.handleChange(set.id).bind(this)} set={set} value={"C"}  />
                                <RadioInput handleChange={this.handleChange(set.id).bind(this)} set={set} value={"D"}  />

                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
                <hr/>
                <div>
                 State:
                 {JSON.stringify(this.state.questions)}
                </div>
            </form>

        )
    }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### Preview Page...

[Preview](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k5r22d?embed=1&file=index.js&view=preview)

Comment: @Sankap Bhamare how do i get the values of each input element when submitting

Comment: Olatunde Temitope they are automatically stored in the `this.state.questions.chosen` , I have made the code so it directly gets stored in the form state. You can see you a chosen field for each question, I have updated the answer selected by user directly to the state.